# MS SQL Обновление таблицы по заданным значениям

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый день есть две таблицы и МSSQL Server2008

```
   CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,Number INT , Value  INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Table2
(
     ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tNumb INT, Name NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES
(492,120),(403,120),(496,110),(495,110),(493,110),(631,130),(702,130),(404,130),(501,140)

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES
(492,'Some1'),(493,'Some2'),(495,'Some3'),(496,'Some4'),(404,'Some5'),(405,'Some6')
```

Нужно обновить данные в Table2.tNumb , заменив на минимальное подходящее значение поля Table1.Number, которые имеют подходящее Value

ответ должен получиться таким:

```
403 Some1
493 Some2
493 Some3
493 Some4
404 Some5
405 Some6
```

Никак не могу составить корректный запрос.

Answer (score 0):

сначала выберите эти минимальные значения, на которые хотите обновить. Соедините первые две таблицы по равенству number=tnumb, а затем приклейте к ним этим минимальные значения.

```
WITH mindata AS (
      SELECT value, min(number) as mn
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY value
)
UPDATE t2
SET tNumb = mn
FROM table2 as t2
INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.number = t2.tNumb)
INNER JOIN mindata AS d ON (d.value = t1.value);
```